# How to distinguish between gui and console apps elf file

Tags: c, linux, elf

I wanted to execute gui only app, but the problem is, i don't know how to check that.

Do you have a solution for this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <elf.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if(argc < 2)return 1;
   char buf[256];
   Elf64_Ehdr elfhdr;
   FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
   if(f == NULL)return 2;
   fread(&elfhdr,1,64, f);
   fclose(f);
   if(elfhdr.e_ident[0] == 127 && elfhdr.e_ident[1] == 'E'
      && elfhdr.e_ident[2] == 'L' && elfhdr.e_ident[3] == 'F'){
      if(elfhdr.e_type == 2){
          sprintf(buf,"./'%s' > /dev/null 2>&1 &",argv[1]);
          system(buf);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean that given an ELF file you want to know if running it will create X11 or similar graphical windows, or if it will stay inside the terminal?

Comment: @John Zwinck, yes only gui from X11,SDL,etc

Comment: You can get close with `ldd executable | grep "libX"` to see if the file is linked against X shared object libraries.

Comment: I do not understand the people who downvote a question merely because the asker misunderstands something about how the platform works. Just because the best answer might be "it cannot be done" does not mean this is not a legitimate question.

Comment: @nimday your question sounds like an XY problem. Could you explain what your actual purpose is? That is, what led you to wanting to make this distinction? Examples: `mpv` uses a GUI if the given file is a video, otherwise it uses a CLI. `qtchooser` is a pure cli program, whose purpose is to transparently replace itself with another dynamically determined program that may or may not show a GUI. The `python` program has the ability to open windows, but only does it if the script it interprets orders it to. Are those examples GUI or CLI to you? Why do you need the distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has no distinction between "GUI" and console applications. That's something that only Windows has. A Linux GUI application is an application that happens to call functions that cause windows to appear.

What you can do is check whether the application links in the GUI libraries. Problem is, it is not easy to determine what those are. The libX is one, but it may not be directly linked (possibly via another library).

`ldd` is a tool you can run that will tell you what libraries an executable links in (including indirect ones). If `libX11` is not on the list, it is *almost* certain that this is not a GUI program. If it is, it is *probably* a GUI program.

Comment: Do you have a small example for this ?

Comment: Just do `ldd filename | grep libX11`.

Comment: Ok, I'll switch to linux to try that

Comment: It is also possible to use X11 protocol without linking X11 in at all. For example `ssh` can be used to run GUI programs from remote host - but it doesn't link in any X libraries.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You can also be working with wayland, a proxy that translates your invented API to X11, or just statically link libX11. That's why I said that if `libX11` isn't there it is --->*almost*<--- certain that this is not a GUI program.

Comment: Also, any program written in a scripting language... my `/usr/bin/firefox` is a **shell script**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I might be splitting hairs, but isn't the fact that `/usr/bin/firefox` is a wrapper script a different problem? Folks seem to be conflating wrapper scripts with executable programs. Her next problem may be to identify the wrapper scripts to find the target executable. But this question only seems to be concerned with native executables.

Comment: @jww it's just that the answer may not be that useful. Many very common programs use wrapper scripts. Some even use wrapper binaries (eg qtchooser). So even checking target is a binary wouldn't work. Not to mention some programs can use either a GUI or a CLI depending on how they are called. Heck, some even choose between those depending on environment settings.

Comment: Indeed. It would be difficult to tell using `ldd` whether the Java JVM created a GUI or not. Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't, depending on the application. X (or whatever) libraries are loaded at runtime if needed, and don't show up in `ldd`.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think the console/GUI flag on _Windows_ is respected any more. You can set this flag using Windows compiler tools, but I don't think there are any ill effects if it is set wrong, so it still isn't reliable.

Comment: @KevinBoone last time I checked (which is quite a while ago) it affected both whether Windows opened a console window for your application when run, as well as what program entry function was expected (main vs. WinMain). I don't see how either of those can change semantics over time.

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh. Fair enough -- it's a long time for me, also. My recollection is that if you set console mode, the console window was only opened when output was produced. You weren't prevented from creating a GUI, by calling CreateWindow(), etc. So the default became to set console mode all the time, even for a GUI application -- if the application produced output to stdout/stderr it would be for troubleshooting, and you'd want to see it. Starting at main() rather than WinMain(), wasn't a problem for GUI apps, as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

This distinction is useless in Unix, as many programs do have both console and GUI behaviours in them. The `ldd` is also as useless as it gets. For example on my computer:

```
% ldd /usr/bin/firefox 
    not a dynamic executable
```

because it is a shell script that runs the actual firefox executable. However, firefox almost surely is run as a GUI application most of the time. `python3` doesn't link in X libraries directly, but any program written in Python could possibly create windows, without executing any other application. `ssh` can be used to execute programs on remote host so that the window is displayed on the X server of the local computer, etc.

If you need to know which one is a GUI program, ask the *user*.

Comment: …and ask every time. `mpv foo.mp3` doesn't create a GUI, but `mpv bar.avi` does.